# Animate position, rotation or scale during cloth simulation

Tags: animation, keyframes, cloth-simulation

well the question it s pretty simple.
My real problem is that I have a chips bag with a cloth simulation, and I d like to animate the position and rotation of the chips bag with keyframes while the simulutaion is playing

Comment: I toyed with this last night - Add an empty centrally to the deformed (cloth) object and parent it to that empty.  Animate the empty not the object.  It will still act as before but is now movable, rotateable etc.  Blend file available if you don't manage it.

Comment: @Edgel3D thanks I`ll defintly try that and see if it works! I tried with an empty but not in the center of the object and that didn`t work, so fingercross with your method (:

Comment: Ah - I can see what the problem is.  My apologies. I have to go off-line and onto my Blender machine to try these things out and I used a soft body on a cube 'bag', not a cloth modifier.

Interestingly, I'm in discussion with another user for exactly this same problem.  My solution has mostly been to apply the cloth modifier in another copy of the Blend-file and import that back into the original, switch to that and doing whatever's necessary.  Cont...

Comment: Further to the above - The change-over is usually seamless and the hard mesh can always be duplicated and given cloth physics again.  See some examples here -

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jackg5k42di15wl/AADyDUDafdPsyX_7P6XfwWFta?dl=0

Comment: https://streamable.com/6bmkws Nothing happened :(
The real thing I want to do is make the bag inflate, then move it and insert it into a box (the box should affect its shape) Thanks for the help again! (: @Edgel3D

Comment: Your inflatable bag shouldn't be too much trouble, if you "Apply" the cloth modifier. That will "Solidify" the bag in it's current shape and can be animated from then on, squashed, bent, you name it with shapekeys or cage rigging. If you're stuck let me know and I'll have a play at my end, see if I can give you a (crude) working example.